# ItemizedIconOverlay Crashes on Single Tap for OSMdroid

Tags: android, android-mapview, osmdroid

I'm using this link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/10585401/3176433 to overlay ItemizedIconOverlay for **OSMdroid**. Unfortunately, whenever I trigger a SingleTap the app crashes.

Fortunately if I override according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20441999/3176433
the **app doesn't crash**. But I dont want to do this.

Because I won't be able to access the Gesture Listener that I've passed for my ItemizedIconOverlay Class. I'm unable to override

```
          new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {

          @Override
          public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(int index, OverlayItem item) {
            Log.d("APP","HERE");
                            //Control Doesn't Come here
            return true;
          }

          @Override
          public boolean onItemLongPress(int index, OverlayItem item) {

              return true;
          }
```

Please Let me know a possible Solution where I can override onItemSingleTapUp?
I did follow related links:[OSMDroid crashes when zooming out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566421/osmdroid-crashes-when-zooming-out), [Adding ItemizedOverlay to my mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573586/adding-itemizedoverlay-to-my-mapview), [Android ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927185/android-itemizedoverlayoverlayitem-issue)

But didn't completely understand though.
**EDIT**
Here's my stack trace:

```
04-10 09:41:24.280: I/Adreno-EGL(9402): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
04-10 09:41:24.300: D/OpenGLRenderer(9402): Enabling debug mode 0
04-10 09:41:27.493: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 99K, 2% free 9394K/9524K, paused 18ms, total 20ms
04-10 09:41:27.603: I/org.osmdroid.views.MapView(9402): Using tile source: org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.XYTileSource@41ed03b8
04-10 09:41:27.613: I/org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileFileStorageProviderBase(9402): sdcard state: mounted
04-10 09:41:27.613: I/org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileFileStorageProviderBase(9402): sdcard state: mounted
04-10 09:41:27.653: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 226K, 3% free 9682K/9940K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
04-10 09:41:27.733: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 163K, 2% free 10025K/10228K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
04-10 09:41:27.783: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 37K, 2% free 10394K/10560K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
04-10 09:41:27.803: I/org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderBase(9402): rescale tile cache from 0 to 5
04-10 09:41:27.813: I/org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderBase(9402): Finished rescale in 4ms
04-10 09:41:27.853: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 84K, 2% free 10819K/10940K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
04-10 09:41:27.903: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 367K, 4% free 11043K/11460K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
04-10 09:41:28.043: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 346K, 4% free 11386K/11764K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
04-10 09:41:28.113: I/SensorManager(9402): This application is using deprecated SensorManager API which will be removed someday.  Please consider switching to the new API.
04-10 09:41:28.244: I/org.osmdroid.tileprovider.LRUMapTileCache(9402): Tile cache increased from 9 to 63
04-10 09:41:28.264: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 407K, 4% free 11776K/12216K, paused 26ms, total 27ms
04-10 09:41:28.344: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 128K, 4% free 12336K/12736K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
04-10 09:41:28.374: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 12882K/13256K, paused 23ms, total 26ms
04-10 09:41:28.444: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 73K, 3% free 13676K/14036K, paused 43ms, total 43ms
04-10 09:41:28.484: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 86K, 3% free 14688K/15076K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
04-10 09:41:28.574: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 600K, 5% free 15621K/16368K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
04-10 09:41:28.804: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1469K, 9% free 16333K/17836K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
04-10 09:41:29.054: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2455K, 14% free 16334K/18820K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
04-10 09:41:29.335: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2484K, 14% free 16303K/18820K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
04-10 09:41:29.605: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2446K, 14% free 16300K/18820K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
04-10 09:41:29.875: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2319K, 13% free 16382K/18820K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
04-10 09:41:30.145: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2077K, 13% free 16382K/18820K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
04-10 09:41:30.486: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2298K, 13% free 16383K/18820K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
04-10 09:41:30.806: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2443K, 14% free 16295K/18820K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
04-10 09:41:31.146: D/dalvikvm(9402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2340K, 14% free 16319K/18820K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
04-10 09:41:31.317: D/AndroidRuntime(9402): Shutting down VM
04-10 09:41:31.317: W/dalvikvm(9402): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41548ba8)
04-10 09:41:31.317: E/AndroidRuntime(9402): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 09:41:31.317: E/AndroidRuntime(9402): Process: com.cassidian.tasp, PID: 9402
04-10 09:41:31.317: E/AndroidRuntime(9402): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 09:41:31.317: E/AndroidRuntime(9402):     at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ItemizedIconOverlay.activateSelectedItems(ItemizedIconOverlay.java:170)
04-10 09:41:31.317: E/AndroidRuntime(9402):     at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ItemizedIconOverlay.onSingleTapConfirmed(ItemizedIconOverlay.java:118)
04-10 09:41:31.317: E/AndroidRuntime(9402):     at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.OverlayManager.onSingleTapConfirmed(OverlayManager.java:233)
04-10 09:41:31.317: E/AndroidRuntime(9402):     at org.osmdroid.views.MapView$MapViewDoubleClickListener.onSingleTapConfirmed(MapView.java:1566)
04-10 09:41:31.317: E/AndroidRuntime(9402):     at android.view.GestureDetector$GestureHandler.handleMessage(GestureDetector.java:273)
04-10 09:41:31.317: E/AndroidRuntime(9402):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-10 09:41:31.317: E/AndroidRuntime(9402):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-10 09:41:31.317: E/AndroidRuntime(9402):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-10 09:41:31.317: E/AndroidRuntime(9402):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 09:41:31.317: E/AndroidRuntime(9402):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-10 09:41:31.317: E/AndroidRuntime(9402):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-10 09:41:31.317: E/AndroidRuntime(9402):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-10 09:41:31.317: E/AndroidRuntime(9402):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 09:41:32.778: I/Process(9402): Sending signal. PID: 9402 SIG: 9
```

Comment: If you are getting an exception, always post it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Searching over internet I found this solution to the problem: créate your own itemizedOverlay.

```
class MyOwnItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem> {

protected Context mContext;

public MyItemizedOverlay(final Context context, final List<OverlayItem> aList) {
     super(context, aList, new OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
        @Override public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
                return false;
        }
        @Override public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
                return false;
        }
      } );
  mContext = context;
}

@Override protected boolean onSingleTapUpHelper(final int index, final OverlayItem item, final MapView mapView) {
    //Toast.makeText(mContext, "Item " + index + " has been tapped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
    dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
    dialog.show();
    return true;
}
```

}

And to use it in your activity:

```
ArrayList<OverlayItem> list = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
MyOwnItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> overlay = new MyOwnItemizedOverlay(this, list);
mapView.getOverlays.add(overlay);
```

you may find this example on the coments of this issue:
http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=245

Comment: This is single tap for item. But real scenario is the while loading of maps if at all you tap some place on the map arena, the single tap function crashes. BTW if I use your approach I would be disabling the touch ability on MapView.